# Can the Yii2 RESTful API return the JSON data in camelcase format?

Tags: json, rest, api, yii, yii2

Is it possible to configure a Yii2 RESTful API to return JSON responses in camelcase format instead of snakecase without creating the column names that way? I can't find any mention in the docs or elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible by configuration alone, to achieve this you need to overwrite the [fields()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-resources#overriding-fields) method
You would need to do this for each model your api exposes

```
class SomeModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return array|false
     */
    public function fields() {

        // what you want is to rename the keys of parent::fields()
        $formattedFields =[];
        foreach (parent::fields() as $key => $name){
            $formattedFields[Inflector::variablize($key)] = $name;
        }

        return $formattedFields;
    }
}
```

`fields()` method is basically a way to add, remove, rename or redefine fields.
The documentation page i've linked goes into more details about use-cases and other examples

Comment: Great idea. Thanks. That's an easy solution.